# Apple Music Authorisation vs Media Library Authorisation

Tags: ios, apple-music, apple-musickit

In order to access the User's Apple Music Library, I need to request authorisation from
`SKCloudServiceController.authorizationStatus()`

Also, there is another authorisation option in `MPMediaLibrary`.

I need to be able to access both user's library and the Apple music library.

During my testing `SKCloudServiceController.authorizationStatus()` returns `authorised` when `MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus()` is authorised and vice-versa. (In iOS settings, user has only one option to toggle the permission for both services, named 'Media & Apple Music')

I need to know, if checking either of these is sufficient enough? Are there any situations where `authorizationStatus` from both places might be different?

Comment: Did you figure this one out eventually? I am working on an exact same requirement here.